# Index not used in simple select query mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, index

I have a simple query on a table with 66k rows and the index is not used.

Query :

```
select * from products p where p.upc = '771313251785'
```

MySQL version : 8

Here is the create table :

```
CREATE TABLE `produits`
             (
                          \n `pharmacieidbjc` INT NOT NULL,
                          \n `upc`            VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `sap`            VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `iditem`         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                          \n `description`    VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `fournisseur`    VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `coutant` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `prix` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `categorie`       VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `sousdepartement` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `departement`     VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `marque`          VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `din`             VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `crx`             VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `esttaxablefed`   TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n `esttaxableprov`  TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
                          \n PRIMARY KEY (`pharmacieidbjc`,`iditem`),
                          \n KEY `ix_upc` (`upc`)
                          /*!80000 INVISIBLE */
                          ,
                          \n KEY `ix_sap` (`sap`),
                          \n KEY `ix_din` (`din`),
                          \n KEY `ix_dep` (`departement`),
                          \n KEY `ix_sousdep` (`sousdepartement`),
                          \n KEY `ix_cat` (`categorie`),
                          \n FULLTEXT KEY `ix_upc_full` (`upc`)\n
             )
             engine=innodb DEFAULT charset=utf8
```

[image: Index configuration]
[image: Plan]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` explains your issue. The index was declared invisible. Read about them at: [MySQL 8.0 docs: Invisible Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html) where it is explained:

> MySQL supports invisible indexes; that is, indexes that are not used by the optimizer. ...

```
ALTER TABLE produits ALTER INDEX ix_upc VISIBLE ;
```

should make the index visible again and be used by the optimizer.

While not disallowed, it is usually inappropriate to have both `FULLTEXT` and `INDEX` indexes on the same column.